# Localhost - meaning of fe80::1%lo0

Tags: macos, localhost, ipv6

What does "fe80::1%lo0" mean "fe80::1%lo0 localhost" the private/etc/hosts file on Mac osx

Comment: in a simple word it's the typical IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1, if you want more use google or read ipv6 rfc

Comment: @sim, that is incorrect, ::1 is the IPv6 address equivalent to the IPv4 127.0.0.1 address. Anything in the FE80::/10 range is a link-local address, more akin to, but not the same as, the 169.254.0.0/16 IPv4 address range. IPv6 interfaces may have multiple addresses assigned, and IPv6 requires a link-local address on each interface. The link-local address range is on each interface, and the link-local addresses may be the same for each interface on a single device.

Answer (score 4):

Addresses in the fe80::/10 range are link-local addresses.  The addresses are only significant to the link on which they reside, so a device with multiple interfaces may have the same address, and certainly will have the same link-local network, on all its interfaces.

That's where the % sign comes into play.  That is the interface id on the device that will distinguish the interface on which the address resides.  Different operating systems will have different values after the % sign.

Comment: Is the interface id after `%` required for other address types as well, or *only* for addresses starting with `fe80` ?

Comment: @jez,  RFC 6874 explains: "_To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local addresses under prefix fe80::/10.  At the time of writing, this is the only well-defined usage known._"

Answer (score 2):

We are considering the record `"fe80::1%lo0 localhost"` in the file `/etc/hosts/` in OS X.

It means for the hostname "localhost" use IPv6 link-local address `"fe80::1"` in zone `"lo0"`. Link-local means that this address is not routable and will be discarded by any router in the local network (at least they should).

As we are talking about OS X, the typical config of OS X "lo0" iface is:

```
lo0: 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
```

From here we can see that the main goal of this link-local address is to support loopback network communication in a link-local address space. But there are few apps which use it.

Comment: You are confusing two different things. The fe80::/10 address range has nothing to do with the ::1 local host address.  The local host interface could have any link-local address.  By default it is fe80::1, but can be changed to any address in the fe80::/10 range. IPv6 interfaces have multiple addresses, and always have a link-local address. The local host interface will have the ::1 address AND a link-local address. fe80::1 could be assigned to all the interfaces since it is only relevant to the link on which it is assigned, and it is not specific or required for the local host interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin I've rewritten my answer to avoid confusion